# Evernote and SBApplication bridge - createNoteWithENML issue - resources added twice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, evernote, applescript-objc

### The problem:

```
//Create Evernote App SBApplication

  EvernoteApplication *evernoteApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.evernote.Evernote"];
    evernoteApp.delegate = self;

//Take this ENML Code
NSString *enml = @"<div>This is an encrypted text for OneNote Saferoom.</div><div><br/></div><div>PDF file</div><div><en-media type=\"application/pdf\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" height=\"43\" hash=\"fa7d7e650b2cec68f302b31ba28235d8\"/></div><div><br/></div><div>Image</div><div><en-media style=\"height: auto;\" type=\"image/png\" hash=\"64957a2bd851f625383a5b9e410965d7\"/></div>";

//Create correct Array of URLS for above (Set the URLs before)
NSArray *resourceURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url2,url1,nil];

//Upload the note to Evernote
[evernoteApp createNoteFromFile:nil fromUrl:nil withText:nil withHtml:nil withEnml:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<en-note>%@</en-note>",enml]  title:noteTitle notebook:workingNotebook tags:tags attachments:resourceURLs created:nil];
```

And now I get the note with additional duplicated resources (Evernote app just adds all resources from resourceURLs array to the end of the note):

[image: Problem with Duplicated resources]

## **Tried the following**

- remove resourceURLs array - no resources added
- using HTML and adding resource URLs - structure is not kept, resources appear at the end only
- converting from ENML to HTML using Inline resources function (ENMLUtility) - resources are not displayed

I am starting to believe that there is a bug in how Evernote.app handles createNote request.

### Resources to test

- PDF sample file for above resource:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8pgzzexms0nl7w/dec-pdf-sample.pdf?dl=0
- Image sample
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/nagaei1hng6ziwc/dec-touchID_blue_80%403x.png?dl=0
- Generated Evernote.h file for bridging:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7u1zdb8c71ydwag/Evernote.h?dl=0

**Any help will be appreciated.**

**Update 1:** 
Tested with pure AppleScript, still resources are duplicated:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvpc4est8ef7q4c/EvernoteAppleScript_bug.scpt?dl=0

Thanks,
Ilia

Comment: Write it in AppleScript. If it breaks there, it's either your own AS code that's wrong or a bug in EN, in which case file a bug report with the AppleScript code attached because AS is the de facto reference implementation against which all scriptable apps are (or should be) tested. If it works in AppleScript, then it's because your own SB code is wrong or because SB is a sack of knackers, in which case fix your SB code (assuming you can figure out how) or use AS (which is the only supported option that knows how to speak Apple events right).

Comment: Just tested it with AppleScript, got the note with duplicated resources as with SB code. Here is the script to test (update paths to your own if you wanna test) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvpc4est8ef7q4c/EvernoteAppleScript_bug.scpt?dl=0 . Waiting for Evernote reaction...They send all questions to stack overflow.

Comment: Don't have Evernote to test on here but definitely sounds like it has a bug. Good luck getting them to the bottom of it.